# Can't find XML files in published C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

So I have created a Windows Forms app in C# using Visual Studio. The app saves data to .xml files in `C:\Users\Me\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug` (default location), and works perfectly when building inside VS.

My program uses simple LINQ expressions to read from the .xml file:

```
XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
// do something with it
```

However, when I try to publish the app and run as a standalone Application Manifest file, I get the following error when I try to read one of the .xml files:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps.......
```

This is obviously cause by an incorrect file path, but how is it fixed? I have tried various methods online but nothing seems to be working. I can't move the .xml files from debug folder without breaking the build. I think I need to do something in the build properties?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @TontonVelu my code simply performs a read function on the xml file using LINQ. It references the file using XDocument.Load("file.xml"). I won't include the code as I don't think it will help explain my issue, this question is more around how visual studio changes the structure of the files once published, and hence, breaks my program. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed the standalone Application is run from your AppData folder (The exe file is actually 'unzipped' and runs from that temp location).

You can use this sample code to get the path that your app runs from (.exe location):

```
var processModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
if (processModule == null)
{
    Environment.Exit(-1);
}
var baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(processModule.FileName);
const string settingsFile = "myfile.xml";
string fullSettingsPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, settingsFile);
XDocument.Load(fullSettingsPath);
```

To prevent your xml file from becoming part of the standalone application you need to add this to your .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="myfile.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps......

Did you publish the application via ClickOnce?

If so, you can include the xml in `Application Files...` .

[image]

And access the file address by the following statement.

```
string filepath = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\myfile.xml";
```